# How to grab color for UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

As we know we change text color of SearchBar by this line of code and it works good:

```
UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.blue]
```

And the placeholder for color is `UIColor.blue`.

The questions is:

**How to grab specific color?**

I have tried to change `UIColor.blue` **to** `UIColor.init(red: 200, green: 200, blue: 200, alpha: 1)`

However no matter what number of red/green/blue/alpha i provide to `init()` i cannot grab a color.

Is there an Enum limitation like **.blue/.red/.yellow**?

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
    public extension UISearchBar 
    {

        public func SetSearchbarcolor(srchcolor: UIColor)
        {
            let Search = subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews }
            guard let Searchfilter = (Search.filter { $0 is UITextField }).first as? UITextField else { return }
            Searchfilter.textColor = srchcolor
        }
    }


Output : Searchbar_name.SetSearchbarcolor(srchcolor: UIColor.colorname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of UIColor.init, try

```
UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 100/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
```